# Jsoup: Extracting innertext from anchor tag

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

Here's my problem. I have a html content:
    
      
            innerText
      
    
I need to extract the "innerText". While trying this in Jsoup I found that the innertext goes outside the anchor tag when parsed by Jsoup.

Here's my code

```
Document doc=Jsoup.parse("<div>  <a href="#"> innerText  </a> </div>");
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div >
   <a href="#"></a>innerText
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

why is "innerText" moved outside the anchor tag?

Comment: Which version of JSoup are you using?

Comment: @SubOptimal Jsoup-1.8.1

Comment: Have checked your code with version 1.8.1 and my posted answer is still valid. The `innerText` is shown inside the `a` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the text by calling the `text()`method on the element.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div>  <a href=\"#\"> innerText  </a> </div>");
System.out.println(doc.html());
Elements rows = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element element : rows) {
    System.out.println("element = " + element.text());
}
```

btw. Using your posted code (and JSoup 1.8.1) produces the following output

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div> 
            <a href="#"> innerText </a> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```