# Scrape a web page using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I need to scrape the postcode from the HTML below by using Jsoup. I only need postcode which is part of `href` attribute of `a` tag. In this example, the postcode part is `W2`:

```
<a href="/properties-for-sale/w2/chpk3848653" class="property_photo_holder" style="backgroundimage:url(https://assets.foxtons.co.uk/w/480/1523289105/chpk3848653-23.jpg)"></a>
```

This is the HTML:

```
</div>

<div id="property_1062067" class="property_summary">

<h6><a href="/properties-for-sale/w2/chpk3848653">Lancaster Gate, <span class="property_address_location_name">Bayswater,</span> W2</a></h6>
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I only need postcode which is W2" ? Also, may you post something you tried?

Comment: I just tried to show what data exactly I want to scrap. Please see the below

Comment: >Bayswater,</span> W2</a></h6>

Comment: This is my code which I tried to scrap

Comment: Elements postcodes = doc.select("span.property_address_location_name");
          for (Element postcode : postcodes) {
              System.out.println(postcode.text());
  
          }

Comment: Only bayswater displayed. I only need postcode part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669496/jsoup-extracting-innertext-from-anchor-tag)

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSOUP for that, you just need to retrieve the href attribute value as it follows:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();

Elements elements = document.select("a");

String href = elements.attr("href");
```

Now that you have the href attribute as a String, you need to apply a RegEx (Regular Expression) to get the field you want, in this case, the Postal Code contained in: "/properties-for-sale/w2/chpk3848653". To do that you will need to:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(href);

String postalCode = matcher.find().group(0);
```

That's all, if you need anything else feel free to ask! Hope this helped you!

Comment: Something is wrong with this code. Thanks for anyway

Comment: @Hakan no problem! ask me if you need anything else, that was just a sample code as guide! +1 if you found it useful!

Comment: This is the code how I scraped all other attributes...etc.

Comment: //Get the location of property
        Elements locations = items.get(i).getElementsByTag("h6");
        
        //Get the post code of property
        Elements postcodes = items.get(i).getElementsByTag("h6.a[href]");                               
        
        //Get the longitude
        Elements longitude = items.get(i).select("div");

Comment: https://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?submit_type=search&sold=1&location=       This is the link to web scraping.